# NSOperationQueue setSuspended:NO failing to start operations back up

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, concurrency, afnetworking

I'm having an issue where I'm testing my app by turning airplane mode on and off to handle intermittent or flaky connections.

Basically I need to queue up requests for submissions from the user and do this synchronously, if the request fails take it out of the queue tell the user it failed then do the next.  The addition of operations can be many at a time or 1 at a time, regardless they need to queue up and execute one at a time.

It's working great until about the 3rd or 4th time I cut off the connection, once I do that, the `NSOperationQueue` of `AFHTTPRequestOperations` do not continue to execute, even though I confirm they're sitting in the `NSOperationQueue`.  I have a custom task class that holds a `AFHTTPRequestOperation` as a property and in its lazy initializer I build up the request.

Here's what I'm basically doing in code:

My custom class that holds a task and a manager (so the request can create itself in a lazy inititalizer).

```
@interface MyTask : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPRequestOperation *request;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end
```

The code inside an operation manager custom class that adds the tasks sent from the viewcontrollers:

```
- (void)addNewRequest:(MyTask *)task {

   [self.operationQueue addOperation:task.request];    
}
```

Here's how I'm handling online offline pausing and resuming of the queue:

```
__block NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = self.operationQueue;
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        [self.operationRequestManager.reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {

            __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;

            switch (status) {
                case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
                    [strongSelf.networkHelper setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
                    [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];

                    break;
                case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
                    [strongSelf.networkHelper setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
                    [operationQueue setSuspended:NO];

                    break;
                case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
                    [strongSelf.networkHelper setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
                    [operationQueue setSuspended:NO];

                    break;
                default:
                    [strongSelf.networkHelper setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
                    [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];

                    break;
            }
        }];

        [self.operationRequestManager.reachabilityManager startMonitoring];
```

I've confirmed that it steps into the resume cases and that there are operations on the operationQueue by sending the operationCount method.  But for whatever reason the process goes to a halt after a few times of going on and offline.

I'm also setting the maxConcurrency to 1 on the opQueue to force synchronous behavior.

```
- (NSOperationQueue *)operationQueue {

    if (_operationQueue == Nil) {
        _operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [_operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    }

    return _operationQueue;
}
```

ETA: have tried setting the operationQueue to atomic to see if it was a thread issue and that didn't resolve it.

Comment: It's possible that one of the operations on the queue is executing at the time and it has gotten stuck by the switch in and out of airplane mode. If the operation is stuck, then the queue has no reason to start another. Iterate over the operations and check `-isExecuting`.

Comment: I'm now canceling all the operations in the queue when the connection is dropped, and recreating the queue when connection resumes and adding back all the tasks.  Still no dice.

Comment: Canceling an operation that's stuck doesn't actually terminate it. Canceling just marks the operation as having been canceled. The operation must check the flag and terminate itself. If it's stuck, it can't check that. It's also possible that a stuck operation is holding some shared resource. Did you check whether any is executing?

Comment: @MarkW Had you resolve this? if yes then plz post solution to this?